# Activity на fullscreen

Tags: android

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Не для всех окон срабатывает.

Comment: Попробую сейчас вот что:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сработало:

```
public class ActivityName extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Также можно использовать разметку:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно в манифесте установить тему fullscreen